# Optional chaining doesn't work on Node 16.4

Tags: javascript, optional-chaining, ecmascript-2020

I have tried this syntax in VSCode and Coderpad (both use Node version 16.4).

```js
let x = {}
x?.something.foo
```

As far as my understanding goes, this code shouldn't throw an error now, but return `undefined`. The feature `optional chaining` should be available in Node v14+ but for some reason it doesn't work in my VSCode and also in Coderpad.

Thought why?

Answer (score 2):

`x` is an existing object for which you want to allow the `something` property to be undefined. Hence, the correct syntax should be `x.something?.foo`

The syntax `x?.something.foo` means: allow an object `x` to be undefined, but if it isn't, return the value of the property chain `something.foo`. Since in this case `x` is defined, but `x.something` isn't, you'll get an error (unless you use `x?.something?.foo`).

Comment: `... you'll get an error (unless you use x?.something?.foo)` thats not true as long as x is defined. The `?` after the `x` is not necessary. `x.something` will be undefined and `x.something.foo` will be an error. `x.something?.foo` will be undefined.

Comment: @aProgger I probably should have written it down more clearly. What I mean is that using `x?.something.foo` will throw an error if `x` is defined but `x.something` isn't (as in OP's example). Using `x?.something?.foo` would be useful if `x` or `x.something` could be undefined.